# invoke Rscript without a script name

Tags: r, rscript

I would like to call Rscript without a proper script, just by writing it in a console. is it possible? something like

```
c:/path/to/R/bin/Rscript.exe "here is a R code, not a R file"
```

I am on Windows.

Comment: Yes, there is the `-e` argument for this. Try for instance: `Rscript -e "{a<-1:10;print(a)}"`.

Comment: if you  can add this as answer I will approve it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run Rscript with -e argument:

```
Rscript -e "getwd()"
```